# Getting child class items only from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<Item> items` and two classes which inherit `Item`, which are `Book` and `DVD`. I add some books and some dvds in the item list

```
items.add(new Book());
items.add(new DVD());
```

Now I want to do a

```
public void printAllBooks()
{
}
```

How can I just pick the `Item` which is of child class `Book` to print only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick solution is to use `instanceof`:

```
for(Item item : items) {
   if(item instanceof Book) {
      // print it
   }
}
```

A more generic solution is to make the method generic, giving it a type parameter and checking if the item type is that of the specified class (or a subclass of it):

```
public <T extends Item> void printItems(List<Item> items, Class<T> clazz) {
    for(Item item : items) {
        // Check if item is of the same type or a subtype of the specified class.
        if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(item.getClass())) {
            // print it
        }
    }
}
```

Then to print `Book` elements:

```
printItems(itemsList, Book.class);
```

and similarly for `DVD` elements:

```
printItems(itemsList, DVD.class);
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "checking if the item is assignable from that type"?

Comment: @Panayiotis I added an example. Correction: "checking if the type is assignable from the item type" (i.e. the reverse but the idea is the same).

Answer (score 5):

If you are forced to use a combined list you can use `instanceof` to check if it's a book..

```
public void printAllBooks()
{
    for(Item i : items){
        if(i instanceof Book){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But a better design might be to have separate lists of books and dvds

Answer (score 3):

```
for (Item item : items) {
    if (item instanceof Book) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
public void printAllBooks(){
  for(Object item: Items)
     if(item instanceOf Book)
        //do what ever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for(Item item : items) {
   if(item instanceof Book) {
      // do something with Book Item
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Guava, you could use the following:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29

For your example, something like this would work:

`Iterable<DVD> dvds = Iterables.filter(items,DVD.class);`